# Value can't be negative

Tags: python, image, int, pixel

I got 2 pixels of a gray image (converted with open-cv) and I want to subtract them:

```
frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame_color, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
for x in range(2064):
   for y in range(1200):
       intensity1 = frame[y, x]
       intensity2 = frame[y + 1, x]
       diff_intensity = intensity1 - intensity2
```

The diff_intensity can only be between 0-255. So if  `intensity1 = 12` and `intensity2 = 16`, I got 252. I want to get -4.
I have tried to convert the difference into int16: `diff_intensity = numpy.int16(intensity1 - intensity2)`  but without success.
Does anyone know how can I do that?

Comment: Sorry, what is the output of `type(intensity1)`?

Comment: @JThistle the type is uint8, that's because it's unsigned! I convert intensity1 and intensity2 into int16 and it works, thaks!

Answer (score 0):

Since `intensity1` is `uint8`, it is an unsigned integer. This means it can only hold a positive value.

You need to convert it to `int8`, like this:

```py
diff_intensity = numpy.int8(intensity1 - intensity2)
```

`int8` is a signed integer, so it can hold negative values.

(You must have imported numpy for this to work.)